# Algebraic Geometry: A question about radical ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm working on this problem: Show that a rational normal curve $C$ of degree $3$ cannot be an intersection of two quadrics.

Here is my solution. Let

$$J=\{\text{$f$ is homogeneous of degree $2$ and $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ in $C$}\}.$$

Then clearly $J$ is a $k$-vector space with dimension $\geq3$. If $C$ is an intersection of two quadrics $p,q$, then $J$ is a collection of homogeneous polynomials of degree $2$ in the radical of the homogeneous ideal generated by $p$ and $q$. However, it is possible that there exists a homogeneous polynomial $h$ of degree $2$ such that $h$ is $k$-linearly independent of $p,q$ and $h^n=pu+qv$ for some $u,v$. However it seems to be true that there does not exist such $h$ and it leads to a contradiction. How can I show that?

Comment: Well, I'm a bit confused here. When you say a curve $C$ of degree $3$, do you mean $C \subseteq P^3$?

Comment: Yes. I mean $(x:y) \mapsto (x^3:x^2 y:xy^2:y^3) \in \mathbb{P}^3$.

Comment: I have another question. When you say $C$ is the intersection of two quadrics $p,q$, do you mean $C = V(p,q)$ as schemes? I'm actually a bit lost in your argument. I thought if a curve in $P^3$ is the intersection of two quadrics, then it has degree $4$.

Comment: In fact I didn't learn about schemes and Bezout's theorem yet.. It is a problem in a former part of K.Hulek's book.

Comment: What is your definition of degree?

Comment: A rational normal curve of degree 3 is defined above, and a degree of a polynomial is what we just know.